# Spring autowiring keeps JMockit mocks around for other tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, autowired, jmockit

I'm trying to unit test a class (let's say, "ClassUnderTest") and its use of a particular library class (let's call it "Helper").  So I'm injecting a mocked Helper into the ClassUnderTest and using Expectations to check things out.

```
 public class TestUseOfHelper {
     @Autowired ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;
     @Mocked    HelperClass    helper;
 [...]
     @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
         Deencapsulation.setField(classUnderTest, "helper", helper);
     }
 [...]
     @Test
     public void test() {
         new Expectations() {{
             helper.doSomething(any);
         }};

         classUnderTest.useHelper();
    }
```

So far, so good.

In other tests (same package, different file), I'm testing other aspects of the ClassUnderTest where I just want Helper to do its thing.

```
 public class TestOtherQualities {
     @Autowired ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;
 [...]
     @Test
     public void test() {
        result = classUnderTest.processSomething();
        assertNonNull(result);
    }
```

Those tests work fine as well.

The problem comes in when I run the suite of tests.  Now, the second set fails, apparently because the Mocked Helper is still in place!

I assume that the full suite is being executed in the same JVM and that Spring has created one ClassUnderTest, injects the mock like it's told, but then just reuses the same ClassUnderTest object for the next test.  How do I keep them separate?  How can I get "fresh" objects for each separate test file?  What am I not getting/googling?

I've tried numerous variations of defining objects within the Expectations blocks and using @Tested/@Injected but with no luck.  BTW, I'm avoiding mocking the Helper in other tests because I need it to do its thing.  Also ClassUnderTest autowires a bunch of other objects, which in turn autowire still others, so mocking everything that ClassUnderTest references is impractical.

Any insights, Oh knowledgeable Stack Overflow Magic 8 Ball?  ("Try Later" is not acceptable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the test class with

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)
```

if you want to reset the app context between test classes.

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I was looking for, but which no amount of Googling was revealing to me!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's a unit test. So you shouldn't use Spring at all to create and autowire the objects. Just create a new ClassUnderTest every time you need one, and inject the mock dependencies manually :

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
    Deencapsulation.setField(classUnderTest, "helper", mockHelper);
}
```

Note: I don't know JMockit, and it might have annotations that even create a new and inject mock dependencies automatically. The point of my answer is that Spring should be out of the picture for unit tests. That's the main advantage of dependency injection: being able to create instances of objects to test, and being able to manually inject mock dependencies.

Comment: Point taken, that ideally each class should be tested in complete isolation.  But implementing injection for everything is sometimes impractical (IMHO).  In my case, I did go back and start to remove all autowiring from the test class and use mocks for everything.  But the class under test does some file and stream operations, so the mocking quickly become more complicated than the code itself.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear from others about using Spring and autowiring in unit tests.  Again, I can understand the purist approach  of using none, but the practicality of using Spring in unit tests really a bad thing?  After all, the application is using Spring, so shouldn't that connection be tested as well?

Comment: If you realise that it's too hard to set up your system under test, that's the point when you should try to change it, because there are too many dependencies :-)